# Automapper 6.0.2 and IQueryable

Tags: automapper

I am using `AutoMapper 6.0.2`. I am trying to use AutoMapper to map my DTO to external model.
I created the mapping config to map both the models as below:

```
var mappingConfig = new   
MappingConfiguration(
cfg =>
cfg.CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>     
().ForMember(...)
);
IMapper mapper =         
mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
```

Then in my controller code, I apply the mapping as follows:

```
 var query = GetDataasModelA().AsQueryable();
    var modelB = query.ProjectTo(mappingConfig);
```

This line, just creates a new instance of `ModelB` instead of mapping the values in query to `ModelB`.
What am I missing here? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why are you using AsQueryable? Is the return value of `GetDataasModelA()` actually an IQueryable? Or just an IEnumerable?

Comment: Its an IQueryable . I am getting an IQueryable from data layer. This one is an example to show that the output of GetDataAsModelA() is an  Iqueryable. I just wanted to capture the way I am using automapper in our code. My requirement is to map an  IQueryable. Do you have any guidelines for this? What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you need to include more information here.